# How to listen for window closing in X11 code?

Tags: haskell, x11

I'm still struggling with Haskell's X11 binding. Now, I want to detect the event of user closing the window. My best attempt so far:

```
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Data.Bits    

main :: IO ()
main = do
 dpy <- openDisplay ""
 let dflt = defaultScreen dpy
     border = blackPixel dpy dflt
     background = whitePixel dpy dflt
 rootw <- rootWindow dpy dflt
 win <- createSimpleWindow dpy rootw 0 0 300 200 1 border background
 setTextProperty dpy win "Hello World" wM_NAME
 mapWindow dpy win
 moveWindow dpy win 0 0
 selectInput dpy win (structureNotifyMask .|. exposureMask)
 updateWin dpy win

updateWin :: Display -> Window -> IO ()
updateWin dpy win = do
  sync dpy True
  allocaXEvent $ \e -> do
    nextEvent dpy e
    ev <- getEvent e
    putStrLn $ eventName ev
  threadDelay (1000000)
  updateWin dpy win
```

But instead of getting the event, I get the following output:

```
ConfigureNotify
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
      after 26 requests (25 known processed) with 5 events remaining.
```

What is causing this? What would be the right way to deal with it?

Comment: Now if you'd not skip the imports, we would actually have a SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch ClientMessage events. There's no mask and no need to select them, just detect them and destroy the window. You also need to set WM_DELETE_WINDOW protocol. See e.g. [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HGL/3.2.0.2/doc/html/src/Graphics-HGL-X11-Window.html). Look for ClientMessage and WM_DELETE_WINDOW.

At some point you will want to intercept other client messages apart from WM_DELETE_WINDOW. You will need to examine ClientMessage contents, not just. the type, but for now it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But with one (huge) problem - the program now seems to ignore Ctrl-C completely. Can it be fixed?

Comment: To be more precise, if launched with runghc, it ignores all Ctrl-Cs, but if I compile it beforehand and run as an executable binary, it responds only to second Ctrl-C.

Comment: I would be very surprised if Ctrl-Cs have anything to do with xlib bindings. I would use System.Posix.Signals and install my own handler anyway.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with blocking in `nextEvent` call, since adding `threadDelay` after it makes exiting possible. I'll try to install my own handler now.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... If I do "installHandler keyboardSignal (Catch (killThread tid)) Nothing", nothing happens on `Ctrl-C`.